# Google QPX API key

Tags: google-api, google-qpx-express-api

I am trying to obtain API key for QPX express but I stuck because QPX is not available in Google API Library on my account (I also tried other account).

[Googe API Library screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwOpE.png)

When I try use the API key without enabling API I get as result:

[QPX with API key screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAgts.png)

When I go to link from description I see:

[QPX api problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGpZe.png)

I followed this instructions - https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/prereqs

Is there any other way to obtain this key?

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same problem and then came across this:

https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/faq#EndOfServiceFAQs

QPX Express is shutting down in April and "New users can no longer sign up for the QPX Express API service"

Answer (score 0):

same for me. i am assuming maybe it's because i am still on the free trial account and that api is not visible until you actually pay monhtly (like aws)
have sent an email  yesterday.. hope someone will come back
Alternatively, can anyone suggest any other APIs i can use? i tried skyscanner but it does not show Ryanayr flights...

kr